# Vulkan shows disabled on google chrome on Ubuntu but showed as enabled on fedora(same laptop)

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, wayland, vulkan

Here is the screenshot on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Vulkan shows as disabled.
[image]

Now, the screenshot of Fedora where vulkan shows as enabled:
[image]

So, how do I enable vulkan on Ubuntu?

**Edit 1:**

Output of `sudo lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (rev 03)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Integrated Sensor Solution (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP DRAM Controller (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Management Engine (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev 30)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34be (rev 30)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34bf (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b4 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX330] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix BC511
```

Output of `sudo find /sys | grep drivers.*00:02.0` :

```
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/ath10k_pci/0000:02:00.0
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/i915/0000:00:02.0
```

**Edit 2:**

[Output of vulkaninfo](https://gist.github.com/ShramanJain/f062b3c9f0046e035eabb1033afdd1d1)

Also, I tried to go to `chrome://flags/#enable-vulkan` and set it to enabled but that just made chrome stop working completely.

Comment: Which graphics card do you have, Intel, AMD or NVIDIA? Which driver are you using in Ubuntu?

Comment: I have intel(i5-1035g1) and nvidia(mx330). I have not installed nvida drivers and have disabled nouveau. And it looks like I am using i915 driver for intel. Found using what [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41817/linux-how-to-find-the-device-driver-used-for-a-device) says.

Comment: Does `vulkaninfo` on Ubuntu show your GPU?

Comment: Here is the ouput of `vulkaninfo` : [link](https://gist.github.com/ShramanJain/f062b3c9f0046e035eabb1033afdd1d1)

Comment: Thanks! Please, tag a `@user` you're answering to, otherwise they won't be notified. I looked at `vulkaninfo`, and I do see the GPU there, so ‍♂️ Another theory I have: it might be due to older Mesa. Ubuntu generally have older software, and the Mesa *(userspace part of graphics drivers)* you're using is 22.0.5, whereas on Fedora it is 22.1.7 or even higher *(depends on whether you're on 36 or 37)*. Chrome might be detecting the version perhaps didn't implement something crucial for them, and so disables by default. For Ubuntu there's a PPA with bleeding-edge Mesa, you might try it.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I tried using a PPA for newer mesa(kisak-mesa PPA) and my mesa version did get upgraded : `OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.4 - kisak-mesa PPA`. But, google chrome still shows vulkan as disabled in `chrome://gpu/`

Comment: Does Chrome still stops working if you enable vulkan at `chrome://flags/#enable-vulkan`? Also, if it does, can you try running it from terminal and see if there's anything interesting appears in the browser output? As a side note, for that kind of experiments you can run chrome as `HOME=/tmp/ google-chrome`, so any changes you do will only be stored in the `/tmp` dir, so you don't have to undo them later.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I tried enabling vulkan through `chrome://flags/#enable-vulkan` and it works now.  ![terminal output](https://imgur.com/a/VY31tQk) The break in terminal is from when i set enable vulkan to enabled and click 'relaunch'

Comment: Nice, so… it's working :) I see one error about VAAPI. I presume you have enabled video hw acceleration but probably didn't install the drivers. You can test if it works outside the browser with `vainfo` command. Other errors Idk what are about. Either way, the problem with making Vulkan work seems solved.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Yes the problem with vulkan is solved. You replied as comment instead of answer so I don't know how to mark it as the accepted answer though. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per research done in comments, the problem turned out to be too old Mesa *(a userspace part of graphics drivers)* on Ubuntu. After upgrading to more recent Mesa version through kisak-mesa PPA, then enabling Vulkan in Chrome, it works now. Mesa version that Chrome Vulkan is proved to be working with is `22.2.4`.

Comment: @Bram what GPUs do you have, what Chromium version are you using?

Comment: I was on r114 and r115, but when trying google-chrome-unstable (116.0.5845.32) it worked. Thanks!