# How to use the packaged ESLint on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, npm

There's an apt package called `eslint` in Ubuntu 22.04, and I intend to use it presumably it's easier to setup.

But when I run `eslint --init` in my project directory, as well as my home directory, it throws a stack of exceptions, saying that the rejection of some `Promise` wasn't handled. And I'd like to know:

1. How do I initialize a project directory for ESLint installed from `apt`?
2. How do I reach the point where official docs for eslint would work for me, or alternatively
3. After I've done 1, what doc should I consult?

Comment: Is it the case that the `eslint` package is outdated?

Comment: Well, yes, https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/eslint says it's at 6.4.0, but https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint is already on 8.35.0. I wouldn't expect there to be a lot of common ground between these the online docs and the version packaged for 22.04. With ecosystems like NPM, you might be better off just using `npm` to install `eslint`.

Comment: @muru Am I right to believe that's a broken unmaintaned package by this point? (Debian sid still has it, also very old.)

Comment: @DannyNiu well, it's not that it's "unmaintained package", rather that Ubuntu sees "old packages" as something cool to have, claiming it's "stable". Aside of a few chosen packages like Firefox and Chromium, Ubuntu never updates its software to newer major version within given distro version. `eslint` ain't special, it's also the problem with core packages like Mesa, Xorg, kernel *(although for some of them there're opt-in hwe versions)*… See e.g. [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1442896/266507). Yeah, it's very sad, but that's the policy of Ubuntu as a distribution.

Comment: `dpkg -L eslint` will list all the files in the `eslint` package. Read some of them. Also `man eslint`. Are you missing libraries that the program needs? `ldd $(type -p eslint)`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel that's not a *claim* - it is *stable*, just a different meaning than what you're thinking of ("stable" as in "unchanging", not "stable" as in "bug-free").